# Failed to use an existing native mongo-db connection in connect-mongo session store

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connect-mongo

**index.js:**

```
..
var MongoStore = require( 'connect-mongo' )( session );
var db         = require( path.join( __dirname, 'db.js' ) );
..
db.connect( conStr, function( err ) {
    if( err ) {
        console.log( 'Connect to mongoDb failed!' );
        process.exit( 1 );
    } else {
        app.listen( port, function() {
            console.log( 'App listening on port: ' + port );
        });
    }
});
...
app.use( session ({
    name: 'bbn.sid',
    secret:'shopusersessionsecret', 
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore( { db: db.get() } ),
    cookie: { 
        maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000,
    }
}));
..
```

**db.js:**

```
...
var database = null;

function connect( url, done ) {
    if( database ) return done();

    MongoClient.connect( url, function( err, db ) {
        if( err ) return done( err );
        database = db;
        done();
    });
}

function get() {
    return database;
}
...
```

If i'm creating the new connection to the session store (by providing url) 
it seems OK, but if i'm trying to use an existing mongo connection i get the following error:

```
E:\Proj\bbn\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:105                                                                                                           
                throw new Error('Connection strategy not found');                                                                                                 
                ^                                                                                                                                                 

Error: Connection strategy not found                                                                                                                              
    at MongoStore (E:\Proj\bbn\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:105:23)                                                                                    
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Proj\bbn\index.js:50:12)                                                                                                            
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
```

It seems, that the session middleware is calling rather then mongo db connection initializes?

Answer (score 0):

Place all app.use middleware inside connect callback:

```
mongoclient.connect(mongourl, (error, database) => {
   if (error) return console.log(error);`

   db = database;

   app.use...
   app.use...
   app.listen...
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/issues/261